# apache start using service - httpd process sleeping

Tags: apache

We have a lot of httpd process in aws webserver that are sleep and maintains a connection with mysql database in another server.   Connections are in sleep state in db server for a long time.  we start the apache server using service httpd restart.   why the httpd process are running as DFOREGROUND .  Want to run the httpd process in background how to do it and not sure so many process are sleeping.

```
319:apache   29542  8044  0 09:00 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
320:apache   30274  8044  0 09:04 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
321:apache   30461  8044  0 09:05 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
322:apache   31575  8044  0 09:11 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
323:apache   31581  8044  0 09:11 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
324:apache   31994  8044  0 09:12 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
325:apache   31996  8044  0 09:12 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: `-DFOREGROUND` is the default unless overriden by `OPTIONS=` in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.

Comment: Excerpt from [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html) _-DFOREGROUND (prevent the parent from calling setsid() et al)_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Have another webserver using amazon linux os . it doesnt show DFOREGROUND on httpd process.  The webserver that running under centos  in aws. shows DFOREGROUND option .  checked the  amazon linux webserver /etc/sysconfig/httpd  of the aws webserver the OPTIONS is commented

Comment: You might want to check the `MPM` configuration and compare them.